# SharpDevelop, How do you add a DataSource?

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am attempting to complete a homework lesson in C#.  I am supposed to add a datasource to a Datagrid view control.  However, in Sharp Develop under the common task menu the datasource dialog has no way to add a DataSource.

This apparently is different than how VS works.  Can someone help me figure out how to do this in SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the datasource programatically, using explicit binding. For example, during the `FormLoad` event (introducing an explicit BindingSource):

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
    private System.Data.DataSet dataSet1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
//...
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataSet1.ReadXml("x2.xml");
        this.label1.Text = dataSet1.Tables[0].TableName;
        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables[0];
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but basically are you saying that the GUI cannot in fact do this?

Comment: You can use the properties window Data section (DataBinding). Is that GUI enough?